# Admin shows entries of a model even though database is empty

Tags: django

How is the following possible?

I cloned a django project into a dir, ran `syncdb`, [check_permissions](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/commands.html#check-permissions), `migrate`, `createsuperuser` and ran my development server. I then went to the `admin` and there I saw 2 entries of a model even though there are no fixtures that could cause these entries. When I looked at my sqlite database file, there are no entries for that model, even though it shows these two entries in the admin(I also did `python manage.py dumpdata > my_db` and case insensitively searched within that file, no result). It's also not browser related because the problem also occurs on a new installed browser.

These 2 entries are entries I made in the development server of the project on another location. But that server is not running and I'm using a different port.

I also grepped (`grep -r -n entry_name`) from my root folder looking for the names of those entries, however without result.

When I select these entries in the admin and click delete, nothing happens. These two entries remain there.

**Edit 1**

@Hedde:

- I did `ps ffaux|grep python` . There is only one Django process running: `/home/my_username/.virtualenvs/project_name/bin/python manage.py runserver 8044`
- I gave each of my settings files a print line to identify when each is running. Only the development settings is run, like expected and has always been the case.
- I am using sqlite3 for the database, there is only one `my_database.db` file in my project dir. (`find . -iname *db*` only returns one database file)

**Edit 2**

- When I clone the project from another pc and do the whole procedure listed above(`syncdb`, `check_permissions`, `migrate`, `createsuperuser` and run development server) everything works as expected, the entries are gone.

Comment: If you didn't load any initial data, then you _are_ looking at the 'other' database. Are you using two separate databases? Are you routing to them correctly? Is your server configuration setup correctly (which processes is accessed?, check your logs and see `ps ffaux`)? Test your db connection and so on.

Comment: I feel bad for you son, you got 99 problems and perhaps a correct settings file is 1. ;)

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Could you take a look at the Edit to the original post?

Comment: @limelights You probably meant an *incorrect settings file*?

Comment: Can you confirm the db file in question is getting an updated timestamp whenever you run a CRUD operation in the django admin view? Also what's your `DB NAME` setting, are you using a full path?

Comment: The `DB_NAME` setting only used `my_database.db`(relative path to project root). I changed it with the absolute path and restarted the server but the problem still occurs. Also when I look at the timestamp of that `my_database.db` file I can see it gets updated whenever I make a new object in the admin.

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide I've made a second edit, could you take a look?

Comment: Could this have anything to do with `Redis`, `Solr` or a `301` error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to `Redis`. Simply [flushing the Redis-db](http://kuyaninjablog.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-flush-memcache-redis/) solved the problem.

```
$ redis-cli
$redis> flushall
$redis> exit
```